# Fire a controller action from a jQuery Autocomplete selection

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a jQuery autoselect box displaying the correct data. Now I would like to fire an ASP.NET MVC 3 controller when an item is selected. The controller should then redirect to a View. Here's my jQuery autocomplete code (I'm sure something is missing in the 2nd Ajax call, but I haven't found it yet):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Client").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Entity/GetClientAutoComplete', type: 'POST', dataType: 'json',
                    data: { query: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item, value: item };
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            minLength: 1,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Entity/GetApplicationsByName/' + ui.item.value, type: 'POST'
                })
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And here's the controller I'm trying to call:

```
 public ActionResult GetApplicationsByName(string id)
        {
            ViewBag.Client = id;
            var apps = _service.GetDashboardByName(id);
            return View("Dashboard", apps.ToList());
        }
```

When I watch the Ajax call fire in Firebug, I see the correct URL configuration, but nothing else happens. It's acting as though it wants to load something rather than send something. I'm confused. Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you sent an `id` by `POST` to the `GetApplicationsByName` controller and the controller is sending back the view.

If you want redirection, you can use the following:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    window.location.href = 'Entity/GetApplicationsByName/' + ui.item.value;
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Yes, someone nearby just informed me that I don't want to make an Ajax call, but should instead treat it more like a form post. Your suggestion may save me more typing, however. I tested it out and it sends the ViewBag reference as expected. Now I need to figure out why the repository isn't returning data, but that's another problem.